# Upload ListArray Of ParseFile To Parse.com

Tags: android, database, parsing, parse-platform

I am trying to upload a ListArray of ParseFiles and I am getting an error and exceptions, and does not upload the file eventually, but when I remove the list it works fine. I already tried to use methods put and addall and its not works. Can someone tell me what can I to do with this?
Part of the code where it failed:

```
public void setPhoto(ArrayList<ParseFile> photos) {
    if (photos != null) {
        this.photosImages = photos;
        addAll("Images", photos);
    }
}
```

And this what i get in LogCat:

> at com.parse.ParseObject.checkpointMutableContainer(ParseObject.java:1022)
>               at com.parse.ParseObject.performOperation(ParseObject.java:2706)
>               at com.parse.ParseObject.addAll(ParseObject.java:2800)
>               at ApartmentData.DataApartment.setPhoto(DataApartment.java:117)

Comment: Hey what are you trying to do here exactly

Comment: decompose it a little bit and use either asyncTask or Post with handler to upload each of the files. you can find examples how to post a file using asyncTask or a handler from android client

Comment: try this "this.saveInBackground();" after "addAll("Images",photos); How big are these images in terms of file size?

Comment: I have an paths(Uri) of images files.i transfer them into PasreFiles and creating a list.Than i want to upload all list of images.The max size of list is  4 items.